# Using C++ DLL in Installscript Custom Action

Tags: c++, dll, windows-installer, installshield, installscript

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I have problems calling a C++ DLL in an Installscript Custom Action. The problem occurs when I try to call my DLL with parameters. The error image looks like this:

1. the DLL is called with parameters
2. the values, the parameters, are successfully processed in the DLL (the values are also successfully transferred)
3. after the DLL method has been successfully completed, no return value is passed but the setup fails with error 1603.

However, if I call the same method without parameters, everything works without problems.

It is irrelevant which parameters or how many parameters are passed. As soon as only one parameter is passed, the setup fails.

Installscript:

```
prototype NUMBER DoSomeThing(HWND, STRING, INT);
prototype NUMBER MsiCppTest.DoSomethingInCpp(STRING, INT);
prototype NUMBER MsiCppTest.DoSomethingOtherInCpp();

function NUMBER DoSomething(hMSi, sText, nCount)
    STRING sSupportDir;
    NUMBER nSize, nResult, nValue;
begin
    nSize = 256;
    nValue = -1;
    MsiGetProperty(hMSi, "SUPPORTDIR", sSupportDir, nSize);
    nResult = UseDLL(sSupportDir ^ "MsiCppTest.dll");    
    if (nResult = 0) then
        //does not work:
        nValue = MsiCppTest.DoSomethingInCpp(sText, nCount);

        //would work:
        nValue = MsiCppTest.DoSomethingOtherInCpp();

        UnUseDLL(sSupportDir ^ "MsiCppTest.dll");
    endif;

    return nValue;
end;
```

C++ DLL:

```
int DoSomethingInCpp(LPCTSTR lpText, int nCount) {
    //The ToDo function is executed successfully with the correct values
    ToDo(lpText, nCount);
    //As soon as the function is completed, the setup is aborted
    return 123;
}

int DoSomethingOtherInCpp() {
    //would work
    ToDo();
    return 321;
}
```

Does anybody has an idea to fix this problem?

Comment: did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty on the exact symptoms and the details of why, but I suspect this could be a [WINAPI / stdcall](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm) vs [cdecl](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/cdecl.htm) calling convention mismatch. Try adding `WINAPI` or `STDCALL` (or `__stdcall`) to your c++ function declarations, or `cdecl` to your InstallScript prototype.